# How do you open a system file explorer in java to select a file for saving or loading?

Tags: java, file, explorer

I am trying to create a simple pixel art drawing application in java. Right now to load and save a file you have to use the console and input the path. I'm wondering how would I open a file explorer and allow the user to select a file through it. I have used a JFileChooser in the past but I'm asking about how to open the OS file explorer. Thanks!

EDIT: I guess I was confusing the first time. I don't want to just open a file explorer I want to be able to have my program interact with it and allow the user to select a file with it. Like this:
[image: Explorer being used in notepad++ to open a file]

EDIT: So I found FileDialog which seems to do what I want except that it is designed for AWT and I am using OpenGL. I can try and make that work but if andyone has anything that works with lwjgl that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can try the [`Desktop` API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html)

Comment: I've used [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615424/how-to-close-a-windows-explorer/19615741#19615741) to show and select a specific file on Windows, but it will limit you to operating on Windows.  I tend to use combination of `Desktop` and this approach depending on the platform the app is running, switching between them as needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a cross platform solution, you could use the `Desktop` API, see [How to Integrate with the Desktop Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html) for more details

Maybe something like...

```
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
    desktop.browse(uri); // Throws
}
```

When running on Windows, I tend to use something like...

```
String path = file.getCanonicalPath();

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("explorer.exe", "/select," + path);
pb.redirectError();
Process proc = pb.start();
```

which will highlight the specified file, but is only suitable when running on Windows

I tend to switch between the two based on the platform the app is running on

Comment: Then AFAIK, not possible, unless you go down a JNA/JNI route

Comment: @GnarlyNarwhal You might consider having a look at https://dzone.com/articles/native-dialogs-swing-little